# Issue with PVC in EKS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, persistent-volume-claims, amazon-fsx

I am trying to create a PVC using AWS FSx serrvice for windows but getting the following error message:

"rror from server (Forbidden): error when creating "pvc-smb.yaml": persistentvolumeclaims "pvc-smb" is forbidden: may only update PVC status"

I was referring the URL: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/using-amazon-fsx-for-windows-file-server-as-persistent-storage-on-amazon-eks/ to utilize FSx as volume.

I am able to create the volume but volume claim is failing with above error message. This is the pvc yaml file:

---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: pvc-smb
spec:
accessModes:
- ReadWriteMany
resources:
requests:
storage: 10Gi
volumeName: pv-smb
storageClassName: ""

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved. Actually system:nodes group does not allow to create pvc. I applied the manifest from different machine which is not a worker node.